# Determining End of Notebook with Mathematica 9

Tags: programming, front-end

The application package I had working in Mathematica 8 no longer works in Mathematica 9.  I believe the problem lies in how I cycle through cells and test for reaching the last cell of the notebook.  In `MyTools\MySubTools1`, I previously used:

```
SelectionMove[nb, Next, Cell];
  While[(*Keep moving cell by cell until the end of the notebook*)
   MathLink`CallFrontEnd[FrontEnd`CellInformation[FrontEnd`NotebookSelection[nb]]]=!=$Failed,
   (*Code*) 
   SelectionMove[nb, Next, Cell]}];
```

but have since changed the code to:

```
SelectionMove[nb, Next, Cell];
  While[(*Keep moving cell by cell until the end of the notebook*)
   Developer`CellInformation[nb] =!= $Failed,
   (*Code*) 
   SelectionMove[nb, Next, Cell]}];
```

To my package I have added:

```
BeginPackage["MyTools`", {"Developer`", "MyTools`MySubTools1`", "MyTools`MySubTools2`"}]
```

The updated code now works as required when debugging in Eclipse but not when running in Mathematica.

What is the best way to check whether I have reached the end of the notebook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Testing for an empty list works ok, e.g.:-

```
ClearOutput[] := Module[{thisnotebook, sel},
  thisnotebook = EvaluationNotebook[];
  NotebookFind[thisnotebook, "EditorInterface[\"Start\"]", All];
  sel = Null;
  While[sel =!= {},
   SelectionMove[thisnotebook, Next, Cell];
   sel = NotebookRead[thisnotebook];
   NotebookDelete[thisnotebook]];
  NotebookSave[thisnotebook]]
```

Comment: Thanks.  This method seems more robust (and easier to read) than the other versions.